# How to print data returned by a process in android using java

Tags: java, android, xml, command-line

I am trying to read an xml file associated with a system app from **my** system app. I am using the following code in java:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /data/data/app_pkg_name/shared_prefs/file.xml");
```

Now as I understand I can do

```
 p.getInputStream()
```

to get the input stream associated with that process. How do I get the actual contents of the xml on the screen in **logcat**, printing it using say, **system.out.println()**?

When I execute the same command (**first one**) on the command prompt in adb shell, I get the contents of the xml file printed on the console. How to do this from within the app?

FYI, my device is **rooted**, and I have used the necessary permissions in my manifest.

Comment: If you want it visible on the device screen you'll need a `TextView` and put the text there. If you `System.out.println` (or `Log.d`) it it will only appear in logcat (which can be viewed via `adb logcat`).

Comment: For now, I want to print using system.out.println. Could you please post a code snippet on how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  /* You can use the below code to print the output using system.out.println() */


StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String contents = "" ;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /data/data/com.admarvel.testerofflineappv242/shared_prefs/myPrefs.xml");
            InputStream inputStream =  p.getInputStream();`enter code here`
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader( inputStream ) );
                while ( ( contents = in.readLine() ) != null )
                {
                    stringBuilder.append(contents);
                }
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("text" + stringBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. One would be to add TextView to your layout, and then set it's content to what you are getting in the stream, eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="" />
```

Then in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.setText(YOUR_STRING_HERE, TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);

    //rest of the code
}
```

You can't output string on screen using system.out.println() in Android. You must use what Android offers (TextViews, Dialogs, Toasts etc.). Please read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) on creating UI.

To print something in logcat, just use:

```
//declare this at the top of your activity
final static String MYTAG = "MyApp";
```

Then use Log.d() whenever you want to print something in logcat.

```
Log.d(MYTAG, "Whatever content you want to put here");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my issue is **how** to get the text returned by the process, not how to display the text once I get it.

Comment: Then please rephrase your question, because as it is now, it implies you're asking us how to display the text.

Comment: Probably I was not clear in my question, but for now, I just want to print the contents I get from that process on the screen in **logcat**

Comment: What do you mean "print on the screen in logcat" - on the device's screen? In logcat window on PC? Please clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

use below method to get data from InputStream in String format and print the returned String...

```
private String getDataFromStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    try {
        final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] bs = new byte[1024];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = inputStream.read(bs)) != -1) {
            String string = new String(bs, 0, read);
            buffer.append(string);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return buffer.toString();
    } catch (Exception exception) {

    }
    return ""; // we got exception or no data in Stream
}
```